# OpenBox tweaks and other

Tags: openbox

I only have one simple question: How to customize the /Debian and the menu design in openbox.

This [link](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/_media/openbox/2.jpg?w=400&tok=22bbd4) here shows an Openbox menu that has a black title in it. How do I do that?

And the /Debian thing, is missing too many applications like Web Browser and doesn't even have icons. How can I make it update, and seperate the directories in /Debian out like CrunchBang?

Comment: Is this about ubuntu?

Comment: Lubuntu is an official flavor supported here. It has Openbox as its default window manager. However, OP needs to clarify the OS.

Comment: @DKBose I use Xubuntu and then installed Openbox.

Comment: You also wrote this: "And for note, I AM running Xubuntu 14.10.4 Trusty Tahr on e17 Desktop Environment." Sometimes, things can get complicated with too many DEs around.

Comment: @DKBose I use e17 because I'm waiting for an answer here.

Comment: @DKBose By the way I've founded this file: `/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml`. So now how do I make it to update itself?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I played with the debian menu thing very briefly. All I use is the plain menu.xml in `~/.config/openbox/menu.xml`. If I need to change things in there, I edit the xml file directly. I don't add or subtract much from my system.

Comment: @DKBose Just want to know how do I seperate the Directory like CrunchBang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add to your `menu.xml` is something like

```xml
<separator label="Openbox 3"/>
```

This produces a separator with the label (or title) `Openbox 3`. If you just have:

```xml
<separator/>
```

you'll get a simple line between items. For example, if you do this:

```xml
<item label="term">
  <!-- stuff goes here -->
</item>
<separator label="Applications"/>
<item label="emacs">
  <!-- stuff goes here -->
</item>
<separator/>
<item label="www">
  <!-- stuff goes here -->
</item>
```

Your Openbox menu will have an `Applications`-labelled separator between the items `term` and `emacs`, followed by a thin line separating `emacs` from `www`.

Of course, there's a lot more to the specification, but adding labelled separators is quite easy.

Comment: @dattutbrus -- Let me know if anything is unclear!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the color of the openbox menu can be done with the program openbox configuration manager or obconf from the command line. Lubuntu comes with several different themes preinstalled. To choose that particular theme for the color of the menu looks like oynx-Citrus. If you wish to add an external theme like one you downloaded from boxlook.org you can click the install new theme and point it at the .obt archive. If you have lxappearnce and lxappearnce-obconf the window border tab also lets you have the same functionality just in a different application.

The content and the items in the menu are actually stored in an xml file. The full specification is found at http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Menus. If you want a GUI application to make your own custom menus I suggest the obmenu package. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/obmenu.1.html

Comment: But I mean the black solid title on top. Even Oynx-Citrus doesn't display.

Comment: @ianorlin, maybe OP should look at `themerc` which is in `~/.themes/Theme_in_use/openbox-3` or in `/usr/share/themes/Theme_in_use/openbox-3`, whichever is appropriate. `themerc` has lines related to `menu.title.bg`, `menu.title.bg.color`, and 
`menu.title.text.color`.

Comment: @DKBose For example, Numix (Because it's also in GTK+) so how do I change it. And also, where can I get the Openbox Bluebird theme and install it?

Comment: You may know that themes can be installed system-wide or user-specific. Anyway, does Numix have an `openbox` subfolder? I have no idea about "Openbox Bluebird". I looked at various themerc files and then I made my own minimal themerc.

Comment: @DKBose ok, first, numix is a built-in theme. Second, you know the Bluebird theme in XFCE desktop? Bingo.

Comment: There are even more themes than there are ones in the repos at box-look.org. I think I could probably make my answer better by including how to add those.